# Interact between 2 webpages?

Tags: asp.net

I have a PM-System.

Now I will have a search:

- When the user hit the search button, a second webpage should open
- In the second page is a user search
- when the user has searched and marked a user, he should click a button
- when he clicks the button, the window should close and the username should be entered automaticly in the first webpage

How to do that?
(ASP.Net, C#, 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side: use jQuery and pop up a form (actually a DIV).  See jQuery and jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in a modal dialog, i think you can use

```
document.parentWindow
```

to access the parent window.